# How can I test for localStorage value in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, local-storage

when I do `localStorage.getItem('user');` I receive this as value:

```
{
    "userDetails": {
        "gender": "",
        "language": "de",
        "color":
      }
}
```

I need to match my logic according to the `language` value. For example if `"language": "de"` do something, if `"language": "en"` do something else.

How can I match the value in key in my example?

Thanks.

Comment: If the data had been stored as valid JSON text, you'd be able to use `JSON.parse`. But without a value for the `"color"` key, that won't work. Is that just an omission here?

Comment: Yeah, color isn't important. Sry about that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getItem` will return a *string*, so the first thing to do is parse it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

Assuming your data is valid JSON (the text in the question isn't but looks like it's meant to be, it's missing a value for `"color":`), that will return the parsed data.

Now you have an object with a property called `userDetails` which, in turn, has a property called `language`, so you can access it via `data.userDetails.language`, perhaps in a `switch`:

```
switch (data.userDetails.language) {
    case "de":
        // ...
        break;
    case "en":
        // ...
        break;
}
```